# Writing a simple DMS web service in Python

Tags: python, web-services, file, content-management-system

I recently learned Python and want to do a project just to get my hands dirty and let the knowledge settle.

So I was thinking to create a simple Document Management System in Python because I have another project written in Java which needs it. I want the two to be linked by SOAP so the DMS will be a web service.

I need the DMS to do basic operations with the files: create them, delete them, manage versioning etc and was looking for some examples, sample code, best practices on how to best do that using Python.

Tried to search the web but could only find full fledged CMS tools with support for DMS. I need something simple, with examples, dicussions, wiki etc.

Does something like this exist?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are a beginner, you should try to avoid Python + SOAP, for it is a dark valley with libraries that do not cover every use case. Use REST.

Comment: Yes, stick with JSON over HTTP or something similar. I've used the SOAP libraries with Python and it's clear how much the open source community hates SOAP. (I tend to agree)

Answer (score 3):

[Mayan EDMS](http://rosarior.github.com/mayan/) a complete free open source electronic document management system, no REST API yet, but all the other parts you need are already coded.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at [django-dms](http://code.google.com/p/django-dms/)
Don't be afraid about [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), it is a framework that will save you a lot of time (and will make you developp neat applications) if you give it its chance.
If you liked python, you will love django.

Answer (score 1):

I used Plone for this sort of thing. They even have the ability for you to generate classes from UML diagrams. Very handy for the corporate world: http://plone.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to build it from scratch you could look at [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/).

CherryPy will provide all the web server type operations, and leave you to build the DMS as you want.

A good book which I used to learn CherryPy is [CherryPy Essentials](https://www.packtpub.com/CherryPy/book).